# how to solve a subdaily2daily problem in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame **dataset** with the **Date** column in dttm format and when doing daily aggregations I get this error, how can I solve it?

```
dataset$Date <- ymd_hms(dataset$Date) 
dailydata <- subdaily2daily(dataset,FUN=mean,na.rm=T,dates=1)
```

> Error in TRUE && (class(dates) == "factor") :
> 'length = 2' in coercion to 'logical(1)'

How can I solve it to create a daily aggregation?

Comment: Please share your data in `dput` format. Visit [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=2